# Active user's details in the HTML page

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I print the active user's details in the HTML page? I am able to print in logs and as well as in sheet but not able to print in HTML

```html
<script>
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);
}
</script>
<p email="email"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure what your asking but here's a simple example of getting current user email on to an html dialog. You could deploy it as a web app if you wish.

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen(e)//for Menu
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
    .addItem('Display Email','displayEmail')
    .addToUi();
}

function getCurrentUserEmail()
{
  var email={'email':Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()};//returned as an object
  return email;
}

function displayEmail()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('getemailinhtml'), 'User Email');//modeless dialog
}
```

getemailinhtml.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(dispEmail)
      .getCurrentUserEmail();
     });//runs after dom is loaded
     function dispEmail(data)
     {
       $('#email').text(data.email);//put's email into h1 tag
     }
     console.log('My Code');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="email"></h1>//Email show up here
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To have your script display HTML pages, start with 
[HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/). A minimal example:

```
function doGet() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var html = '<html><body>Email: ' + email + '</body></html>';
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}
```

Go to "Publish > Deploy as web app" and set appropriate options, so that the app will run as the user accessing it (who will have to authorize it):

[image: web app]

Note that the above example is only suitable as a demo; for larger pages you will want to use [templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) and other web-oriented features of Google Apps script.