# How I make a pop up box in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I create a dialog box with the options "yes" or "no" so that if the person clicks yes, it will run a function in Google Script.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit the question and add some code that you have tried.

Comment: Here's a more general purpose pop up or dialog: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45148465/7215091

Comment: Here's a dialog for sending emails: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59585277/7215091

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Browser.msgBox()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgboxprompt) and pass the desired [ButtonSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set).

```
function getConfirmation() {
  var response = Browser.msgBox("Are you sure?", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  if (response === "yes") {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the [Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) when creating the popup boxes as you can do more with them:

For a simple yes no box, use an [alert](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alertprompt,-buttons) box

```
function alertBox() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  //create the message box, style is ("Title","Message", Buttons)
  var response = ui.alert("Response", "Yes to run, no to stop", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO) //Buttons: YES_NO, OK, OK_CANCEL, YES_NO_CANCEL
  if (response = ui.Button.YES){
    //enter your script here
  }
}
```

Trust this helps you to solve the question!